# Software that can archive files in a directory into multiple zip files, each holding 10 files

Tags: windows, archiving, file-compression, zip

I'm looking for archive software with these requirements:

- Ability to archive files into multiple .zip files, each holding a max of 10 files
- Compatible with Windows 10

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, etc. – so asking how to achieve that with WinRAR on Windows 10 is off-topic here. It *might* be a fitting question on SuperUser (please check with their `/help/on-topic` page before posting there). From your *intention*, a question fitting here would be asking for "software running on windows 10 that can archive files in a directory into multiple zip files, each holding 10 files".

Comment: This is _starting_ to look more like a software recommendation now.

Comment: @Lafix Do you have any preference regarding the names of the resulting zip files?

Comment: I dont understand the use case. E.g. you have 20 files, 10 files at 1 GB, 10 files at 1 kB. Why would you want 1 zip archive with 10 GB and another one with 10 kB? It makes much more sense to split by size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is quite specific, I'm not sure if something with that functionality exists out-of-the-box.

My suggestion would be to use something like a custom script, which would
also give you good flexibility.

Since you are using Windows, I quickly developed a simple **PowerShell script** for you.

Create a *.ps1* text file (e.g. *Create-MultiZip.ps1*) with the following content:

```
param
(
    # The input folder containing the files to zip
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $InputFolder,

    # The output folder that will contain the zip files
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $OutputFolder
)

Set-Variable SET_SIZE -option Constant -value 10
$i = 0
$zipSet = 0

Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | ForEach-Object {
    $zipSetName = "archive" + ($zipSet + 1) + ".zip"
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -Update -DestinationPath "$OutputFolder\$zipSetName"
    $i++;

    if ($i -eq $SET_SIZE) {
        $i = 0;
        $zipSet++;
    }
}
```

Then run it in a PowerShell environment, providing the folder containing the
files you want to zip, followed by the folder which will contain the zip
files. For example:

```
Create-MultiZip.ps1 C:\tmp\input C:\tmp\output
```

What does the script do?
Basically it gets a list of all the files in the input folder, then each file is added to the *archive1.zip* file in the output folder, until the prefixed set size is reached. At that point, a new *archive2.zip* file is created, the same as before... and so on, until all the files in input have been processed.
Note that the resulting files are called `archive<n>.zip`, where `n` represents the progressive number for each zip file.

**The heart of the script is the [`Compress-Archive`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx) [cmdlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Cmdlets). It was recently introduced with PowerShell 5.0, which comes by default in Windows 10.**

If you know Powershell a bit, the script can be easily improved, for example by adding a `CompressionLevel`, or some text output to the console.

It's also straightforward to change the number of files you want in each set, you just need to modify the constant value at the following line:

```
Set-Variable SET_SIZE -option Constant -value 10
```

I've tested the script briefly and it works fine - it goes without saying that you should give it a go on some test files first.